# prerequisites for Hilbert spaces

Tags: soft-question, hilbert-spaces, advice

I was reading about Hilbert Spaces and I found it very interesting. I would Like to further understand and study them. I am still a first year undergraduate student and in my university that is only taught later on in Functional Analysis, but I allays enjoyed to learn new things and expand my mathematical knowledge by my self. Right now I know:

- Linear Algebra
- Real Analysis
- Multivariable Calculus
- Vector Calculus
- Complex Analysis

Is this enough for my to start studying Hilbert spaces? If not, what else do I need to learn first? I do think that I could grasp the more superficial concepts with the things I know right now, but my objective is to get a good and solid understanding of the topic.

Comment: It differs between degrees, so perhaps you were taught some of this during your courses, but to study Hilbert spaces, you will need some knowledge about Operator Theory (Functional Analysis), and understand infinite dimensional vector spaces and bounded/unbounded operators.

Comment: PS. I am sure there are many resources out there, but this is one I'm currently using myself and it covers some of what you're looking for. If you search "Frederic Schuller Quantum Theory Notes" on google, the first link should take you to a website with a downloadable PDF file, which gives a very elementary treatment of some of the basic concepts behind Hilbert spaces (and more generally Banach spaces).

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, I'm not quite into the subject yet, but how are Banach spaces linked to Hilbert spaces?

Comment: By definition, a Hilbert space is complete w.r.t. the metric induced by the norm (which is in turn induced by the inner product). Since a Banach space is defined to be a complete vector space, equipped with a norm, every Hilbert space is a Banach space (the converse statement need not hold).